# getElementById() won't work

Tags: javascript, html

I want to insert a basic form into my website so my users can search for recipes.  I'm having a hard time getting the javascript to find the input value from the form.  Any help would be appreciated.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
  function searchURL()
{
    var foodSearch =  window.open("http://search.myrecipes.com/search.html?N=17&mFil=false&Ntt=" + "document.getElementById("searchFood").value");

};
  </script>
  </head>

<body>

<form>

<fieldset>
<legend>Search for Healthy Diet Recipes</legend>
<p>
Type in the name of the Recipe or Healthy Diet Food you would like to cook below:<br>
</p>
<br>
<input type="text" id='searchFood' >
<input type="button" value="Find Delicious Food" onClick="searchURL()">

</fieldset>
</form>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Did you look at the error in your console? That would be a great place to start.

Comment: [Learn how to **debug** JavaScript](http://www.netmagazine.com/tutorials/javascript-debugging-beginners).

Answer (score 5):

Do not add it into `""` quotes.

Use this:

```
var foodSearch = window.open("http://search.myrecipes.com/search.html?N=17&mFil=false&Ntt=" + document.getElementById("searchFood").value);
```